# Virtual (linux kernel) usb mass storage device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb

I want to test some code which interacts with usb mass storage device through libusb. Consider that on test sever I can't use real (hw) usb device. Also test infrastructure is running in a separate container (not in VM) so I can't create virtual usb device. Is there a way in linux kernel to simulate usb mass storage device? If you have any other idea how I can go on with this, please, share. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) driver will do. It allows you to see a usb device over a network connection as if it was local.